# HTML Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `WebUtility.HtmlEncode("Neil o'Brein")`, which gives output as 
`Neil o&#39;Brein`.

Where `&#39;` is the Html entity for the single quote (apostrophe). But when used the same function with XElement:

```
XElement document = 
    new XElement("JobTicket", 
                 new XElement(
                      "Version",               
                      System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("ART'1")));   
document.Save(@"D:\Test\Test.xml");
```

The output got was `Neil o&amp;#39;Brein`.

Why extra `&amp;` is coming while using in XElement?

Comment: Please format your question. It's hard to see what's the actual question, code sample and error quote.

Comment: Thanks I am working on it...

Comment: Show your code involving `XElement`.  I suspect you haven't realised that `XElement` is escaping content for you.  It's also not clear why you're using `HtmlEncode` in conjunction with XML.

Comment: Well, `XElement` correctly escapes `&` to `&amp;`. Why do you `HtmlEncode` the string before writing it into the `XElement`? And wouldn't `var element = new XElement(tagName, "Neil o'Brein")` produce what you want?

Comment: XElement document = new XElement("JobTicket",
                       new XElement("Version", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("ART'1")));
            document.Save(@"D:\Test\Test.xml");

Comment: In case of any special characters, like  (>,<,&,',',")... that need to escape it in xml while saving..

Comment: `XElement` already does all the necessary escaping! Try `XElement document = new XElement("JobTicket", new XElement("Version", "ART'1")); document.Save(@"D:\Test\Test.xml");` and see if the result is what you want.

Comment: @ Corak... yeah its correct but need to escape the ampersand also while saving it in Xml node.

Comment: @Corak its not transforming the characters like (single quotes('),DoubleQuotes(").. etc) (Needed HTML encoding also). But it will convert some non allowable xml characters like (>,<,&.. etc).

Comment: Do you want to store the string `"Neil o'Brein"` or the string `"Neil o&#39;Brein"` in the xml?

Comment: But there's no need to escape those quotes in XML.  What are you actually trying to do here?  Why do you want to encode the quote?

Comment: @CharlesMager My business need was to translate all the special characters while saving in Xml. sorry, i don't know where it will affect the business.

Comment: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html - "For normal text (not markup), there are no special characters except < and &" -- no need to escape `'` inside the value of an element.

Comment: @user3454340 ... better go and find out why you need this ... because "translate all special characters" without knowing *which* characters are *special* ... well you get me

Comment: If you really need this (you really shouldn't), then you'll have to use something other than `XElement`.  Even parsing `<e>Neil o&#39;Brein</e>` it will convert your character reference back to an apostrophe.

Comment: If you do: `string -> htmlEncode -> xmlEncode -> xml` when *writing* the xml data, then just make sure that you do: `xml -> xmlDecode -> htmlDecode -> string` when *reading* the xml data. -- the xml "encoding/decoding" part is done by `XElement` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new XElement(XName, Object)` constructor you use:

```
new XElement("Version", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("ART'1"))
```

Already does the proper escaping for you when writing the contents to XML. Simply remove the call to `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()`.

Comment: I accept the answer. Yet need to convert all special character to html encoding before saving in xml.

Comment: No, you don't need that.

Comment: Unless, off course, you want to store html in xml, in which case your example input and output is right. I have worked with webservices that expected xml containing strings representing xml.

Comment: @Martijn sure, but then OP shouldn't be surprised of their output, which is exactly as you describe. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "in which case your example input and output is right". It's one of those times where the right thing is deeply profoundly wrong.